Role for Interactive elements in Menu Header
My application has a navigation menu pop-out panel that has a header with a home link and a filter dropdown above the list of menu items (which I cannot change).  From what I understand (from a third-party accessibility audit), any interactive element ("input, button, textarea, select, or A elements") within a section marked with the role "menu" needs to be marked with the role of "menuitem".  So the debate is - should the whole panel be marked as role="menu" and the link and dropdown in the menu header be marked with role="menuitem" too, even though they are separate from the main list of menu items; or should just the container for the list of menu items be marked with role="menu"?  Or is there another option?
Let me know if you need any other information, a sketch of the page, etc.

Are we talking about a real application here, and focus being managed within the menu, meaning that arrow keys are used to focus menu items? If not, the menu role should not be used at all, but rather the Disclosure Navigation Menu as mentioned by the APG.
